# A binomial tail sum inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, binomial-coefficients, concentration-of-measure

Let $n$ be a positive even integer and $x_1,..,x_n$ be iid, $\mathop{Bernoulli}(\frac{1}{2})$ random variables. Let $S_n = x_1 + .. + x_n$. Let $0\leq k \leq \frac{n}{2}$ be an integer.
By [Hoeffding's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality), $$\text{Pr}\left[S_n-\frac{n}{2}\geq k\right] \leq e^{-\frac{2k^2}{n}}$$

Hence, we have

$$ 
\binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}+k} + \binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}+k+1} + .. + \binom{n}{n} \leq 2^{n}e^{-\frac{2k^2}{n}}
$$

Is there a direct proof for this inequality?

Comment: Does $p=\frac{1}{2}$ in your case ?

Comment: I forgot to mention it. I have added it to the question.

Comment: I'd say you can use the fact that $\binom{n}​{k}​=\binom{n}​{n-k}​$ to rewrite your sum as $\sum_{i=0}^{n/2-k}\binom{n}{i}$ and you can then use the results from https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17202/sum-of-the-first-k-binomial-coefficients-for-fixed-n, there are apparently a couple ways to prove directly bounds that are tighter than what Hoeffding/Chernoff gives

Comment: Thanks. It is not immediately clear why the bound in Michael Lugo's answer is better than the one by Hoeffding's inequality. I'll plot both the bounds and see.

Comment: Also one thing I was thinking of that might help for comparison is that as you probably know the sum of all binomial coefficients is simply $2^n$. With the Hoeffding formula, you can do a little upper bound via $e^{-2\frac{k^2}{n}}\leq 2^{-2\frac{k^2}{n}}$, so that your bounds now reads $\sum_{i=0}^{n/2-k} \binom{n}{i}\leq 2^{n(1-2(\frac{k}{n})^2)}$, a reminder that this partial sum is only a fraction of $2^n$. Hopefully, finding a direct bound may lead to something of the form $2^{n(1-f(n, k))}$ for some $f$, making it easier for a comparison.

Comment: One bound that is particularly nice uses the binary entropy function, and says in your case that $\sum_{i=0}^{n/2-k}\binom{n}{i}\leq 2^{nH(1/2-k/n)}$ (you can find it  here --> https://mathoverflow.net/questions/261428/approximation-of-sum-of-the-first-binomial-coefficients-for-fixed-n). You can visually check that it is tighter than the Hoeffding bound --> https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sphqnjzpls

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

$S_n$ is a sum of $n$ i.i.d Bernoulli random variables with each $x_i\sim Bernoulli(\frac{1}{2})$ (according to what you wanted to prove). Then $S_n\sim Binomial(n,\frac{1}{2})$ and $\mathbb E[S_n]=\frac{n}{2}$.

Now, let's evaluate $\mathbb P\left[S_n-\frac{n}{2}\geq k\right]$ :
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P\left[S_n-\frac{n}{2}\geq k\right]&=\mathbb P\left[S_n\geq k+\frac{n}{2}\right]\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n/2} \mathbb P\left[S_n= k+\frac{n}{2}\right]\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n/2} \binom{n}{k+\frac{n}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k+\frac{n}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-k-\frac{n}{2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n/2} \binom{n}{k+\frac{n}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{2}\times2\right)^{k+\frac{n}{2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n/2} \binom{n}{k+\frac{n}{2}}\\
\end{align*}
On the other hand, using Markov's inequality $\forall s>0, \forall k\in\{0,...,\frac{n}{2}\}$, and the independence of $x_i$ :
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P\left[S_n-\frac{n}{2}\geq k\right]&=\mathbb P\left[e^{s(S_n-\frac{n}{2})}\geq e^{sk}\right]\\
&\leq \dfrac{\mathbb E\left[e^{s(S_n-\frac{n}{2})}\right]}{e^{sk}}\\
&\leq e^{-sk}e^{-\frac{sn}{2}}\mathbb E\left[e^{s(S_n)}\right]\\
&\leq e^{-sk}e^{-\frac{sn}{2}}\left(\frac{e^s+1}{2}\right)^n\\
&\leq \frac{1}{2^n}\left[e^{s(-k-\frac{n}{2})}(e^s+1)^n\right]
\end{align*}
Since $k\in\{0,...,\frac{n}{2}\}$, then $(-2k)\geq(-\frac{n}{2}-k)$
$$\frac{1}{2^n}\left[e^{s(-k-\frac{n}{2})}(e^s+1)^n\right]\leq \frac{1}{2^n}\left[e^{s(-2k)}(e^s+1)^n\right]$$

This is the best I could do. Hope it helps a bit.

There's always (first answer) the direct use of Hoeffding's inequality :
$$ \mathbb P\left[S_n-\frac{n}{2}\geq k\right]=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n/2} \binom{n}{k+\frac{n}{2}}\leq e^{\frac{-2k^2}{n}}$$
Mulitplying by $2^n$ gives us
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n/2} \binom{n}{k+\frac{n}{2}}=\binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}+k} + \binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}+k+1} + .. + \binom{n}{n} \leq 2^n e^{\frac{-2k^2}{n}}$$

Comment: I understand this. My question was whether there is a simpler proof of the inequality that doesn't use Hoeffding's inequality (or something simpler than unrolling the proof of Hoeffding's ineq.)

Comment: @MathewsBoban I thought you needed a proof for it. I will try to find one !